# spresenseのサンプルプログラムでmp3再生時にエラーが出る

Tags: spresense

spresenseのMP3を再生するサンプルプログラムを [Spresense Arduino チュートリアル](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_tutorial_audio) の通りにやったのですが、シリアルモニタに以下のメッセージが表示されました。
何が問題なのでしょうか。`0x22` や `0xf1` とは何のことでしょうか。

```
initialization Audio Library
Open! 218417304
Play!
Attention: module[6][0] attention id[2]/code[26] (objects/media_player/media_player_obj.cpp L1371)

Attention!
ERROR: Command (0x22) fails. Result code(0xf1) Module id(0x6) Error code(0x14) Error subcode(0x0)
loop!!
Error End
ERROR: Command (0x23) fails. Result code(0xf1) Module id(0x6) Error code(0x1)
```

Comment: 音楽ファイルに問題があったようです。ネットのフリー素材では再生できました。

Answer (score 1):

私のところでは問題なく再生できていますね。エラーコードですが、これ、むちゃくちゃ分かり難いのですが、[Spresense SDK 開発ガイド](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html)を参照すれば引けます。ここで エラーコード”0x14”で検索してみると次のような内容がひっかかりました。

> AS_ATTENTION_SUB_CODE_DSP_EXEC_ERROR
> 0x14
> DSPの処理でエラー

DSPファイルがきちんとインストール出来ていないのかも知れません。[DSPのファイルのインストール](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_dsp_%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)をもう一度試してみてはどうでしょう？